# SOAP API: TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, xml, soap, postman

I am trying to fetch some data from SOAP API using following code:

```
from zeep import Client


url = "https:/my_url.php?wsdl"
client = Client(url)
badgeNoList = [1111]
apiKey=12345
res = client.service.myService(apiKey, badgeNoList)
```

Which gives: `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

The doc string provide following information:

```
myService(apiKey: xsd:string, badgeNoList: ns0:badgeNoList, emailList: ns0:emailList) -> return: ns0:UnitEmployeeList
```

Not sure if this helps but when running with Postman I use following xml tags:

```
<badgeNoList>
   <badgeNo>
    1111
   </badgeNo>
   <badgeNo>
   1112
   </badgeNo>
</badgeNoList>
```

The error mention that int is not iterable so I thought put it in a list would work but it does not.

**EDIT**

zeep documentation: https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/

The stacktrace:

```
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File <command-2592992161222246>, line 15
     13 badgeNoList = [{'badgeNo': 61410}]
     14 # apiKey=12345
---> 15 res = client.service.wsdlFindEmployees(apiKey, badgeNoList)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/proxy.py:46, in OperationProxy.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     43 if soap_headers:
     44     kwargs["_soapheaders"] = soap_headers
---> 46 return self._proxy._binding.send(
     47     self._proxy._client,
     48     self._proxy._binding_options,
     49     self._op_name,
     50     args,
     51     kwargs,
     52 )

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py:123, in SoapBinding.send(self, client, options, operation, args, kwargs)
    108 def send(self, client, options, operation, args, kwargs):
    109     """Called from the service
    110 
    111     :param client: The client with which the operation was called
   (...)
    121 
    122     """
--> 123     envelope, http_headers = self._create(
    124         operation, args, kwargs, client=client, options=options
    125     )
    127     response = client.transport.post_xml(options["address"], envelope, http_headers)
    129     operation_obj = self.get(operation)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py:73, in SoapBinding._create(self, operation, args, kwargs, client, options)
     70     raise ValueError("Operation %r not found" % operation)
     72 # Create the SOAP envelope
---> 73 serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
     74 self._set_http_headers(serialized, operation_obj)
     76 envelope = serialized.content

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/definitions.py:224, in Operation.create(self, *args, **kwargs)
    222 def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
    223     assert self.input is not None
--> 224     return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/messages/soap.py:79, in SoapMessage.serialize(self, *args, **kwargs)
     77         body = soap.Body()
     78         envelope.append(body)
---> 79         self.body.render(body, body_value)
     80 else:
     81     body = soap.Body()

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py:232, in Element.render(self, parent, value, render_path)
    230         self._render_value_item(parent, val, render_path)
    231 else:
--> 232     self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py:256, in Element._render_value_item(self, parent, value, render_path)
    254 if xsd_type != self.type:
    255     return value._xsd_type.render(node, value, xsd_type, render_path)
--> 256 return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/types/complex.py:307, in ComplexType.render(self, node, value, xsd_type, render_path)
    305         element.type.render(node, element_value, None, child_path)
    306     else:
--> 307         element.render(node, element_value, child_path)
    309 if xsd_type:
    310     if xsd_type._xsd_name:

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/indicators.py:256, in OrderIndicator.render(self, parent, value, render_path)
    253     continue
    255 if element_value is not None or not element.is_optional:
--> 256     element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py:232, in Element.render(self, parent, value, render_path)
    230         self._render_value_item(parent, val, render_path)
    231 else:
--> 232     self._render_value_item(parent, value, render_path)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/element.py:256, in Element._render_value_item(self, parent, value, render_path)
    254 if xsd_type != self.type:
    255     return value._xsd_type.render(node, value, xsd_type, render_path)
--> 256 return self.type.render(node, value, None, render_path)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/types/complex.py:307, in ComplexType.render(self, node, value, xsd_type, render_path)
    305         element.type.render(node, element_value, None, child_path)
    306     else:
--> 307         element.render(node, element_value, child_path)
    309 if xsd_type:
    310     if xsd_type._xsd_name:

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/indicators.py:256, in OrderIndicator.render(self, parent, value, render_path)
    253     continue
    255 if element_value is not None or not element.is_optional:
--> 256     element.render(parent, element_value, child_path)

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/any.py:126, in Any.render(self, parent, value, render_path)
    124 def render(self, parent, value, render_path=None):
    125     assert parent is not None
--> 126     self.validate(value, render_path)
    128     if self.accepts_multiple and isinstance(value, list):
    129         from zeep.xsd import AnySimpleType

File /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-5037d3b7-04a5-4ff0-91a0-b14e49dff392/lib/python3.10/site-packages/zeep/xsd/elements/any.py:188, in Any.validate(self, value, render_path)
    186 else:
    187     if not self.is_optional and value in (None, NotSet):
--> 188         raise exceptions.ValidationError("Missing element for Any")
    190     self._validate_item(value, render_path)

ValidationError: Missing element for Any
```

Comment: It might need to be a list of dictionaries: `[{'badgeNo': 1111}]`

Comment: 1. What is `Client`, where is it defined/imported. 2. Please provide the whole traceback.

Comment: What is the library you are using? Can you link the documentation?

Comment: I have update my post with imported libraries and stacktrace now